# JSLint claims certain recursive function calls are "out of scope"

Tags: javascript, recursion, jslint

I have a [JavaScript snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/kvygb6on/) with a recursive function call:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var recurse = function (x) {
        if (x <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        return recurse(x - 1);
    };

    recurse(3);
}());
```

This does nothing but call itself a few times, but it runs.

Pasting the above into [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) gives me this error:

```
'recurse' is out of scope.
```

However, if I paste in the following snippet, (using a function declaration instead of var):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    function recurse(x) {
        if (x <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        return recurse(x - 1);
    }

    recurse(3);
}());
```

JSLint loves it, no errors.

I know that the goal of JSLint is to prevent bugs in JavaScript code. Does anyone know why JSLint thinks the first one is bad JavaScript? What bug am I preventing by not making a recursive call in the first way?

**EDIT:** To any future visitors to this question: Neither of these JavaScript snippets throw any errors in the latest version of JSLint.

Comment: JSLint is a drag. The first isn't bad JavaScript. [JSHint](http://jshint.com) has no trouble with it. Nor does [ESLint](http://eslint.org).

Comment: I think what JSLint is *trying* to tell you is that at the time you define your function expression, the variable `recurse` has the value `undefined`. This is not a problem, of course, because by the time you actually *call* your function, `recurse` *is* defined.

Comment: No, scratch that -- if you simply do `var recurse;` and then `recurse = function...` that makes the warning go away without changing the situation I described above at all. The real issue is that JSLint doesn't register `recurse` as being in-scope until the entire `var recurse = ...` expression is evaluated (but the left-hand side along ought to be enough for it to know that).

Comment: @apsillers *sigh* - JSLint causes so much anguish, and in this case it didn't even get the complaint right! It should come with a warning on the label.

Comment: @apsillers Thank you for the observation about how to make the error go away. I hadn't tried declaring the var first and assigning it later.

Comment: @squint Idk, JSLint has done well by me. Much less arguing over what settings a team should set, etc., &, bugs aside, Crockford's rules are never objectively *wrong*. See [my comment, below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787474/jslint-claims-certain-recursive-function-calls-are-out-of-scope#comment55347505_33788303), though. Crockford [rewrote JSLint in May](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/557afd32bcaa35480d31a86f02d3a8c06a4e5b5c#diff-01d3d81a6eb6d82af3c377b55dc4fa28), and this ES6 ready version isn't as well tested as the old version was yet. (It's still a beta, imo.)

Comment: How does jslint react to `var recurse = function recurse (...`

Comment: @JaromandaX It complains that there was a "Redefinition of 'recurse' from line [number]."

Comment: @ruffin: *"'recurse' is out of scope"* is objectively wrong. But then I generally dislike Crockford's advice and overall attitude so that makes me like JSLint that much less.

Comment: @squint Check [my comment below again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787474/jslint-claims-certain-recursive-function-calls-are-out-of-scope?noredirect=1#comment55347505_33788303). I really think this question reveals a bug in JSLint "2015". As I said above, "bugs aside", JSLint's suggestions have never been objectively wrong. Again, note that the old JSLint *doesn't* throw an error for this code. His new version is, unfortunately, still pretty raw. If I don't see a post on his Google+ group in a day or so, I'll mention it to him. He's very responsive when you find a screw up like this.

Comment: @ruffin: Alrighty then, it's a bug. I still dislike JSLint.

Comment: @squint It will hurt your feelings. ;^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with either style. As far as I can tell, this is an inappropriate warning.

The issue appears to be that a variable declaration that includes an assignment does not cause JSLint to register the presence of the declared variable name in scope until the entire assignment is evaluated. That is, when JSLint reads `var recurse = ...`, it does not realize `recurse` is a declared variable until after it evaluates the right-hand side of the assignment. In this case, the right-hand side includes a function that makes use of the declared variable `recurse`, but JSLint didn't know about the existence of `recurse` yet, because it hadn't finished parsing the entire assignment.

Consider that this code works *exactly the same* as your `var` example but produces *no warnings* in JSLint:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var recurse;
    recurse = function (x) {
        if (x <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        return recurse(x - 1);
    };

    recurse(3);
}());
```

By drawing out `var recurse` as a separate statement, JSLint first learns that `recurse` is declared in the current scope, and *then* parses the assignment. With your combined `var recurse = ...` (which, again, is not wrong), JSLint erroneously parses the assignment first and then learns about the existence of `recurse`.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer until someone tells me what could go wrong with the first example. Thank you!

Comment: I bet it's because `recurse` is used inside of the `recurse` definition, and the edge case hasn't been caught yet. It works in [the old version of JSLint](http://rufwork.com/jslint), for what it's worth. [After a near complete rewrite in May](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/557afd32bcaa35480d31a86f02d3a8c06a4e5b5c#diff-01d3d81a6eb6d82af3c377b55dc4fa28), Crockford took the new one out of beta a while ago, but it's still got a number of bugs. You might report this at his [Google+ group](https://plus.google.com/communities/104441363299760713736). It's a legitimate bug, I think.

Answer (score 0):

When you are defining the function, the variable recurse is not defined yet, that's why JSLint says it is out scope, claiming that may be undefined and that point.